# How to get Attribute value in place of id?

Tags: attributes, customer-attribute

'sales_executive' is my custom customer attribute. I'm using `$collection->addAttributeToSelect('sales_executive');`
This gives id of 'sales_executive' in the grid. How to obtain option label or value in place of id?

Answer (score 2):

Try this updated code:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load(1);

$attribute = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute('sales_executive');
if ($attribute)
{
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($customer);
}
```

Comment: Ya. This is the error.
Fatal error: Call to a member function getResource() on a non-object

Comment: Please find updated code above